# confirm == true not work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, prompt

I have many div's with a class called "option". I have a button that assigns an id "clicked" to the currently clicked option div. This works great!!

I have another button that brings up a confirm window. When the confirm window asks "ok" or "cancel", clicking OK, is suppose to remove/delete the div with the "clicked" id. This is not working.

Does anybody have experience with this?

```
$(".appoval-button").on("click", function () {
    return window.confirm("Are you sure?");    
    if (confirm("Are you sure?") == true) {
        $("#clicked").remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: You are `return`ing from the function.  No code can/does run after your `return`.

Comment: You never get to the second confirm if the first is yes/true. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @j08691: Or even if it's no, you *never* get to the 2nd confirm.

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes very true

Comment: Your saying I have two confirms here? its not just the one      confirm("Are you sure?")???

Comment: Figured it out!!!! thanks I removed the "return". It prompts me twice now, but I'l figure it out - thanks!

Comment: @ab3d_work: `window.confirm("Are you sure?")` and `if (confirm("Are you sure?") == true) {`.  That's 2 confirms.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use `return` you are exiting from the function early, and returning the result of whatever comes after it. In this case, it is the result of `window.confirm("Are you sure?")` when you call it **for the first time**.

When you call `confirm()` **for the second time** it is never reached. Note that `window.confirm()` and `confirm()` are the same things.

You want to use the result of `confirm()` directly like so:

```
$(".appoval-button").on("click", function () {
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        $("#clicked").remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't return when you call `window.confirm()`. There's also no need to use `== true` in an `if()` condition when something only returns a boolean.

```
$(".appoval-button").on("click", function () {
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        $("#clicked").remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I didn't realize "confirm" was a reserved word. this worked just fine:

> $(".appoval-button").on("click", function () {
>           if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
>               $("#clicked").remove();
>           }
>       });